# Overengineered checkroot in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need help with bash scripting (which i'm mastering atm).

I want to make better checkroot to invoke `su`, `sudo`, etc.. if invoked from non-root user.

**Terminal:**
`kreyren@dreamon ~ $ scripter --something`

**Codeblock:**

```
# ROOT CHECK
checkroot () {
    if [ $UID == 0 ]; then
    echo "Root is detected."
    break

    # Using `sudo`
    elif [ $UID != 0 ] && [[ -x sudo ]]; then 
    echo "Scripter needs root permission to proceed, trying using sudo."
    #TODO: Make the script invoke scripter with CLI argumments.
    sudo scripter #expected to be invoked with --something.

    # Using `su`
    elif [ $UID != 0 ]; then 
        echo "Scripter needs root permission to proceed, trying to log-in as root."
        #TODO: Make the script invoke scripter with CLI argumments.
        su -c "scripter"   #expected to be invoked with --something.
fi
}
```

I'm using https://gitlab.com/argent/avasile as a test subject for this codeblock.

The codeblock should be able to grab invoked command and reinvoke itself with specified variable AKA resolve "TODO"..

Where i'm currently at: https://github.com/Kreyren/random-scripts/blob/master/checkroot_WIP.sh

Conditions:
1) must be part of function to be universal.
2) must be made without additional user-input excluding parsing a password.

---

I spent 5 days with it and i'm out of ideas my best solution so far seems to be grabbing it from `history`?

Thanks anyone for more info including theory AND/OR concept.
- Krey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bourne shell special variable `$@` to call the script again with all the original arguments:

```
exec sudo scripter $@
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work! I was trying to use it before, but it seems that Shell is unable to use `$@` for scripts with separate libs as mensioned above or it's probably author's coding. WIll investigate further.

Comment: What i find out: if i have functions above cases i can't use $@, but if i have cases above functions i can't use functions (code thinks that those are commands to be parsed in terminal), but i can use $@... Tested on https://github.com/RXT067/KULUS/blob/master/kulus.sh

Comment: Solved the issue by defining $@ for function definitions in cases. thanks for info.